# Backup MySQL database through Java Swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing, xampp

I am currently trying to make a program that can backup a MySQL database through the use of JButton. This code creates a file successfully but the file is always empty. It also fails to terminate so I believe something is wrong with the waitFor() function.

I created a replica of this and have tried to remove the waitFor() function and just simply used try...catch and then the only problem would be having the program actually creating a back up.

I am planning to make it restore the database later too but I'd like to fix one problem at a time.

```
private void btnBackupActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    Process p = null;
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        p = runtime.exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe -uroot -p --add-drop-database -B test -r" + filename);
        
        int processComplete = p.waitFor();
        if (processComplete == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup Complete!!!");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup failed!!!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

private void btnBrowseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    JFileChooser path = new JFileChooser();
    path.showOpenDialog(this);
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    
    try {
        File f = path.getSelectedFile();
        location = f.getAbsolutePath();
        location = location.replace('\\','/');
        filename = location + "_" + new Date() + ".sql";
        jTextField1.setText(filename);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters. 2) Do something more useful with exceptions than merely show the message in an option pane. Log them or dump the stack trace. 3) This problem has nothing to do with Swing, despite the button and option panes. ..

Comment: .. First solve it using a console application.

Comment: I am fairly new to all this, what do you mean by solving it using a console application?

Comment: *"what do you mean by.."* Which part do you not understand? I do not intend typing a paragraph to explain 6 words.